# Can anyone help find the bug in my R function? I'm trying to format variables in the dataset

Tags: r, function, debugging

I am trying to keep the variable names in the same style for all my dataset. I wrote this function `style` so I can run it every time before I start working on a new dataset. The first part of formatting seems to work, but I can't return the post-formatted variable names back to my dataset. Could anyone point out what I did wrong? Thanks a lot! (BTW, this is my first post!)

```
# create a dataset for test #

colClasses = c("character", "character", "character")
col.names = c("nstl.day", "Date", "clutch size")

df <- read.table(text = "",
colClasses = colClasses,
col.names = col.names)
df

library(dplyr)

# Here is my function #

style <- function(x){
  n <- names(x) %>%
  tolower() %>%                  #make all variable names lower case
  {gsub(" ", "_", .)} %>%     #replace space to underscore
  {gsub("\\.", "_", .)} %>%     #replace dot to underscore
  {gsub("\\.", "", .)}       #delete dot

  names(x) <- n #return the new variable names back to the dataset (doesn't work)

}

style(df) # the variable names are still the same...
```

Comment: What is the programming language?

Comment: @JJJ It's R. Sorry that I forgot to mention in my post.

Comment: Several things to note: (1) R will automatically substitute `.` for a space in your variable names, so you don't need the first `gsub`; (2) no need for the last `gsub`, as the prior one has substituted `_` for the `.`; and, (3) the code blocks (`{}`) around the `gsub` calls are not needed.

Comment: @EdwardCarney thank you so much for extra points! You make my codes lighter. I really appreciate.

Comment: You function doesn't return `x`. That's why nothing changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Values passed to functions in R are generally not modified. You need to return new values from the function.  R behaves more like pass-by-value than pass-by-reference. If you modify something that's passed to a function, a new private copy of that variable is made just inside the function. You would need to return this modified object so you can use it later. Your function should either return the updated data.frame

```
style <- function(x) {
  n <- names(x) %>%
    tolower() %>%                  #make all variable names lower case
    gsub(" ", "_", .) %>%     #replace space to underscore
    gsub("\\.", "_", .) %>%     #replace dot to underscore
    gsub("\\.", "", .)       #delete dot

    names(x) <- n
}
df <- style(df)
```

or it can return updated names

```
style <- function(x) {
  names(x) %>%
    tolower() %>%                  #make all variable names lower case
    gsub(" ", "_", .) %>%     #replace space to underscore
    gsub("\\.", "_", .) %>%     #replace dot to underscore
    gsub("\\.", "", .)       #delete dot
}
names(df) <- style(df)
```

But it should return something new that you need to save.

Comment: thanks for the explanation about the logic behind R. That's the thing I really want to learn to help my coding skill in the future. Really appreciate.